# how to change folder permission in cms made simple

Tags: permissions, content-management-system

im working with cms made simple.my problem is my template folder permission.in this cms when a template uploaded,a folder (by the same name of that temlate,for example : 'TEMP1') creates and it's permission is set to 0755.when i want to change permission of the template folder i will get this error :

> FileOp Failure on: /home/visamast/public_html/uploads/arty1: Operation not permitted

and also when i want to upload files via ftp or cpanel to this folder nothing will happen,i mean the upload process will be done,but no files has been uploaded!!!!!!!!

how can i fix this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you are having an ownership problem rather than a permission problem. If your server is set up to run PHP as a module, files and directories created by PHP will be owned by the generic Apache user. Generally that means that you will not be able to change permissions on the file/directory. Most likely you will need to have your hosting company do a recursive chown on the entire directory tree your site is in to make you the owner of all of the files and directories.